# Scraping a website by clicking each hyperlinks in a page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape a page where there are ads of places to stay. In order for me to get the address of this places I need to click each one of them and just scrape an address part then come back do this to the next one. This process goes for several pages.

I am using beautiful-soup for scraping and selenium for browser access.

```py
import urllib2
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from time import sleep

erasmusu_base = "https://erasmusu.com/en/erasmus-barcelona/student-housing?english=1&id=261&p="
hdr= {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}

# For the time being lets scrape up to page 2
# This for loop is for moving to the next pages
for i in range(0,2):
    erasmusu = erasmusu_base+str(i)
    page = urllib2.Request(erasmusu, headers=hdr )
    content = urllib2.urlopen(page).read()

    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get(erasmusu_base)

    ad = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/div[2]/h3/a')
    ad.click()
```

First, I am trying to click the ad and open a tab so that I can get the price information. Then I will continue this process for the rest of the ads.

Comment: What isn't working with your code? Please make your question explicit. Please try to make it a single question in the first instance. The title seems to suggest a slightly broader remit than the end line so perhpas align them.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Selenium to get round the protection on the website.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import re

erasmusu_base = "https://erasmusu.com/en/erasmus-barcelona/student-housing?english=1&id=261&p="
hdr= {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}

# For the time being lets scrape up to page 2
# This for loop is for moving to the next pages
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
for i in range(0, 2):
    browser.get(erasmusu_base)
    sleep(5)
    # Hide cookie pop up.
    if browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.hide_cookies_panel"):
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a.hide_cookies_panel").click()
    sleep(1)
    # Get a list of links to visit.
    hrefs = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('h3 a')]
    # For each link get link.
    for href in hrefs:
        browser.get(href)
        sleep(5)
        # Use BeautifulSoup to parse address.
        soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
        # Use regex for address text and find price by class
        print(soup.find(text=re.compile('^Address|^Dirección')).parent.text, soup.find('span', {'class':'priceflat'}).text)
browser.quit()
```

Outputs:

```
Address: Carrer de la Garrotxa, 7, 08041 Barcelona, Spain 450 € / month
Address: Carrer de la Boqueria, 08002 Barcelona, España 800 € / month
Address: Carrer del Dos de Maig, Barcelona, Spain 495 € / month
Address: Carrer de Sant Ferran, 08031 Barcelona, Spain 340 € / month
Dirección: Carrer d'Arenys, 08035 Barcelona, Spain 400 € / mes
...
```

If you are on Python 2.7 add as the first line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and change:

```
re.compile('^Address|^Dirección')
```

to

```
re.compile(ur'^Address|^Dirección')
```

It will look horrible in a terminal but if you write it to file will look OK.

Comment: This works fine until I come up with this page. 
https://erasmusu.com/es/erasmus-roma/alquiler-habitaciones-estudiantes/piso-reformado-con-una-habitacion-individual-libre-450e-938285

I don't know what is happening.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?